# Different behaviors with URLDownload and Import?

Tags: import, url

I don't understand why `URLDownload` misses the MIME type here:

```
u = "https://slack-imgs.com/?c=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%\
2Fmedia%2FDXtFQp2UMAAQtX6.jpg";
URLDownload@u
Import@u
```

[image]